# Can we achieve ATOMICITY in our smartcontract transactions?

Tags: solidity, transactions

The scenario is:
I have 2 smartcontracts and **contractA** calls the method in **contractB**. Lets assume a transaction is signed in one of the method in **contractA** which does something and then also calls the method in **contractB**. Now, something happened and method in **contractB** throws an exception and transaction fails and reverted. However transaction failed but certain transaction fee gets deducted while making the call.

Is there a way to rollback the transaction like we usually do in **DBMS** when something fails in the middle?

Can we somehow achieve the ATOMICITY properties like in DBMS?
Or what is the best approach at least we can practice in smartcontract transactions?

Answer (score 1):

Transactions are already atomic by nature.

Contracts/functions do not sign transactions. Only EOAs (Externally Owned Account, such as your wallet) sign transaction. A contract function can simply call another contract, within the same transaction.

When a transaction reverts, you are charged the gas fees until the revert happens. This is so that you couldn't DoS the network with reverting transactions for free. Nodes do need to spend time to execute your transaction regardless.